# Row repeating when using TOP on odd number of rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using the following queries to produce 2 forms, each displaying half of the items in the table. This selects the top half:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM products
ORDER BY products.product_ID;
```

And this selects the bottom half

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM products
ORDER BY products.product_ID DESC;
```

The obvious problem is that when the items are odd, the middle item displays on both forms. 
I tried solving it using the COUNT() function in various ways but it just will not work with TOP. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the odd number of rows issue when you define the first half.  Then define the second half as those rows not present in the first half.  You could use a subquery with `IN()`, but a `LEFT JOIN` approach like this could be significantly faster.

```sql
SELECT secondhalf.*
FROM
    products AS secondhalf
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT product_ID
        FROM products
        ORDER BY product_ID ASC
    ) AS firsthalf
    ON secondhalf.product_ID = firsthalf.product_ID
WHERE firsthalf.product_ID Is Null;
```

The subquery, *firsthalf*, is nearly the same as the first query in your question.  But in this situation, we only need the `product_ID` from that subquery.

`LEFT JOIN` in the main query means it will return all rows from `products` ... those which match `firsthalf.product_ID` plus those which don't match.  Then the `WHERE` clause filters out the matches ... leaving only the `product` rows which don't match the subquery rows.

It might be easier to understand if you save `products` with a different name, make a new `products` containing only a few rows and then experiment with the query.  Discard the `WHERE` clause and change the first line to `SELECT firsthalf.product_ID, secondhalf.product_ID`.

Comment: That worked but I have no idea what you did. Care to explain?

Comment: I tried but I'm unsure whether my explanation is adequate.  Play with the query as I discussed in the last paragraph.